# How can I download a file from blob storage inside an Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azcopy

I'm trying to download a file I've uploaded to Azure blob storage which I want to use during an Azure Pipelines build.

I am using the `windows-latest` Microsoft-hosted vm to build.

I've tried making a powershell script and using `azcopy`, but I haven't been able to get it to authenticate. I've tried looking through the documentation but there are so many terms, acronyms, and different ways of doing things, that I am lost. It seems that since I am using a vm provided by Azure, I should be able to somehow use the built-in authentication without having to pass credentials, but I can't figure that out. I tried `azcopy login --identity` but that didn't work either. I've also tried running through Azure Powershell, but that didn't make a difference

In one part of my pipeline I use the tool installer task for installing the java JDK--all I have to do is pass it a Service Connection and it works without problems. Both the JDK and the installer are in the same blob, so can I somehow use the Service Connection to authenticate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to execute [az storage blob download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download) command in Azure cli task to download files from Azure Blob Storage:

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@1
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: {service connection}
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     mkdir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BlobFile
     az storage blob download --container-name $(containername) --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\BlobFile --name "{file name}" --account-key $(accountkey) --account-name $(accountname)
```

Using `mkdir` to create a folder in current directory, then download file from blob and save it into this folder. Service connection is integrated into this task, so you can configure the service connection to connect to your Azure blob. Then select it in this Azure cli task.

Comment: I had to add the script type to get it to work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops

`scriptType: ps`